# How to change the console_loglevel in linux?

Tags: linux, kernel, proc, debugging

I read at multiple places (e.g. here http://elinux.org/Debugging_by_printing), that you can change the console log level by echoing an integer to /proc/sys/kernel/printk. If that worked shouldn't the first integer have changed to 5 below?

```
[root@localhost printk]# cat /proc/sys/kernel/printk
4   4   1   7
[root@localhost printk]# echo 5>/proc/sys/kernel/printk

[root@localhost printk]# cat /proc/sys/kernel/printk
4   4   1   7
```

I tried this on multiple systems and it didn't change on any of them!

Comment: Ouch! You must leave a space between a number and `>` or the shell will redirect that file descriptor. Use `echo 5 >/proc/sys/kernel/printk`. Or `dmesg -n 5`.

Comment: you're right. that works solves the problem. thanks!

Comment: sudo sh -c 'echo 8 > /proc/sys/kernel/printk'

Comment: @debug Note that the user is already root.

Answer (score 5):

Moved comment to answer.

You must leave a space between a number and `>` or the shell will redirect that file descriptor. Use

```
echo 5 >/proc/sys/kernel/printk
```

Or

```
dmesg -n 5
```

Comment: https://elinux.org/Debugging_by_printing offers an information about the meaning of different log levels

Answer (score -1):

Please try this.

```
echo 5 4 1 7 > /proc/sys/kernel/printk
```

Comment: You might want to explain things further and provide links to documentation.  Taking random advice on the Internet to do things that may be harmful (messing with /proc) is certainly not a practice to foster.

Comment: In addition to that, the question has already been answered — see the comments underneath the question. The existing answer reflects the comment which resolved the asker’s problem.